# Can’t see any questions in list for ruSO.meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, russian-stackoverflow

After select ruSO.meta as site from left menu can’t see any question.

> [image: empty active]

Questions list only retrieved when I select “Votes” or “Unanswered (my tags)” at top right box.

> [image: full votes]

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-D802
- OS Version: 5.0.2 (152331922a212)

Comment: Look like an error with the API as [this](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=meta.ru.stackoverflow&run=true) returns an 500 error for me.

Comment: I expect this to be a data related problem, caused by [this meta question](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3931/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-used-%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) but I have no idea why or how.

Comment: [taking the first 2 questions from the API works](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#page=1&pagesize=2&order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=meta.ru.stackoverflow&run=true), taking [3 questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#page=1&pagesize=3&order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=meta.ru.stackoverflow&run=true) fails with an 500 internal_error again. That indicates a data related issue for me.

Comment: @rene that is my question too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed and it's out now.